# Can I use my C++ DLL within ActivePivot?

Tags: java, dll, activepivot

ActivePivot being a Java solution, how can I re-use existing C++ libraries in it?

I consider a CVA (CounterParty Value Adjustment) project based on ActivePivot and I would like to reuse my existing C++ code to apply my Collateral logic on array of doubles aggregates by ActivePivot. Is there a special post-processor to call C++ code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ActivePivot post-processor is a normal Java class. There is nothing special about it. So you can use any existing technique so call a C++ DLL function while inside a Java program.

This can be achieve for instance with JNA and BridJ. I don't consider JNI as in most cases, you don't need to use such a low-level API.

For instance, with BridJ:
Given a C++ header looking like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int multiply(double multiplier, int size, double* const vector);
```

I made the following class:

```
import org.bridj.BridJ;
import org.bridj.Pointer;
import org.bridj.ann.Library;
import org.bridj.ann.Runtime;
import org.bridj.cpp.CPPRuntime;

// Generated with http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/
@Library(CPP_Collateral.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME)
@Runtime(CPPRuntime.class)
public class CPP_Collateral {
public static final String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME = "dummy";

static {
    // In eclipse, the DLL will be loaded from a resource folder
    // Else, one should add a program property: -Djava.library.path
    BridJ.addLibraryPath("src/main/resources/DLL");

    BridJ.register();
}

/**
 * My dummy.dll has one method:
 * int multiply(double multiplier, int size, double* const vector)
 */
public static native int multiply(double multiplier, int size, Pointer<Double> vector);
}
```

and my IPostProcessor is simply

```
@Override
protected Object doEvaluation(ILocation location, Object[] underlyingMeasures) throws QuartetException {
    double[] asArray = (double[]) underlyingMeasures[0];

    if (asArray == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        // Size of the array
        int size = asArray.length;

        // Allocate a Pointer to provide the double[] to the C++ DLL
        Pointer<Double> pCount = allocateDoubles(size);

        pCount.setDoubles(asArray);

        CPP_Collateral.multiply(2D, size, pCount);

        // Read again: the double[] is copied back in the heap
        return pCount.getDoubles();
    }
}
```

In term of performance, here I worked on 2.000 double[] of size 10000 and the impact is of about 100ms